# Открытие виртуального COM порта

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, serial

Есть устройство, которое может записывать в заданный COM порт. Нужно считать данные  с этого COM порта. 
Осталось создать ком порт, что бы от туда считывались данные. Как это сделать на с++/qt?

Comment: QSerialPort попробуйте

Comment: Работаешь с портом, используя те же функции что и для работы с файлами. CreateFile, ReadFile, WriteFile. Вместо имени файла - номер порта "COM1" например. Это имя зарезервировано системой и вместо создания файла будет открыт порт.

Comment: @YuryMelnikov спасибо, очень помогло. а кроме `COM1` можно будет еще открыть?

Comment: Имена с COM1 по COM9 зарезервированы. Если нужно использовать порт имя которого >9  то используешь такую запись при CreateFile:"\\\\.\\COM25"

Comment: @YuryMelnikov добавили бы как ответ, я бы принял его